# How to add Comodo PositiveSSL Certificate into Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015

Tags: ssl-certificate, claims-based-identity, windows-server-2012-r2, bluehost, dynamics-crm-2015

Can anybody help me how to add the Comodo PositiveSSL Certificate which I Purchased from Bluehost to Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015.

Now, what I want is to add the Wildcard SSL Certificate to Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 which I installed on-premise in Windows Server 2012 R2.

I want to access the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2015 externally by configuring IFD (Internet Facing Deployment).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/niran_belliappa/archive/2014/01/16/step-by-step-configuring-crm-2013-internet-facing-deployment-ifd.aspx

http://www.interactivewebs.com/blog/index.php/crm/how-to-set-up-crm-2015-ifd-on-windows-2012-and-adfs-3-0/

Just a couple of the many links about the subject. 
It's actually quite simple, just follow the listed steps and you'll be okay (the procedure is *way* too long to copy paste here).

The first link shouldn't ever die, being from MSDN.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

But the problem now that i'm facing is that when i'm trying to import the certificate that i bought from bluehost as an ".pfx" file, 

it says that "certificate does not contain a private key"

why it says that I don't have private key and how to obtain it? 

thanks.